# Writing a custom Keras layer that returns a vector from a dictionary for a given token

Tags: python, keras

I'm working on a problem where I've tokenized a corpus, but there are specific words that have additional features I want to add to an embedding layer's output. The output dimension needs to be the precomputed vectors dimension + the embedding dimension. I'm storing the specific words in a dictionary where `word_dict[token_idx]` returns the `token_vec`.

I'm trying to build a custom Keras layer that will look up those integers from a passed in dictionary, and this is what I have so far:

```
class SpecialWords(Layer):
    def __init__(self, words_dict, output_dim, **kwargs):
        super(SpecialWords, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.words_dict = words_dict
        self.output_dim = output_dim

        # pad the words_dict vectors to the output_dim shape
        for key in self.words_dict.keys():
            vec = self.words_dict[key]
            self.words_dict[key] = np.pad(vec, ((0,output_dim-len(vec)),(0,0))).T


    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.words_table = self.add_weight(
            name='milestone_table',
            shape=(len(self.words_dict), self.output_dim),
            initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(np.array(list(self.words_dict.values()))),
            trainable=False
        )
        
        super(SpecialWords, self).build(input_shape)
    

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):

        # looks up the vectors 
        vecs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.words_table, inputs)
        
        return vecs
```

I keep getting errors about, in this case, the `vecs` in the `call` function not existing when I try to compile the model using the Keras functional API. The model look like this:

```
input = Input(shape=(None, 1), dtype='int32')

embedding_branch = Embedding(input_dim=N_tokens, output_dim=D_embedding+D_words)(input)

external_branch = SpecialWords(words_dict=words_dict, output_dim=D_embedding+D_words)(input)

merged_model = Add()([embedding_branch.output, external_branch.output])
```

Any tips on what I'm missing here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: Also, it appears you are not using `external_branch`.

Comment: I just realized I could probably do this with an `Embedding` layer, will report back with a solution on Monday